# Why is my child component not firing a passed props function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My parent code looks like this:

```
    handleDocumentModalClose = () => {
        setDocModalVisible(false);
        console.log("Modal was closed by parent");
    };
```

and in render I'm creating the child like this:

```
<DocumentsModal
    test="prop test"
    visible={this.state.docModalVisible}
    onCloseHandler={this.handleDocumentModalClose}
/>
```

my child component is:

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, View, Text, Button } from "react-native";

const DocumentsModal = props => {
    // const { onCloseHandler } = props;
    return (
        <Modal visible={props.visible}>
            <View>
                <Text>{props.test}</Text>
                <Button title="close" onClick={props.onCloseHandler} />
            </View>
        </Modal>
    );
};

export default DocumentsModal;
```

I'm sure it's just a dumb error on my part, but I cannot figure it out. How can I properly pass a function in props so that my child component will call it's parent's method (in this case handleDocumentModalClose) on the button click?

Comment: Is the console log running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **`onPress`**, (not `onClick`)!

```
  <Button title="close" onPress={props.onCloseHandler} />
```

See the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button#onpress)

Comment: thank you, sometimes it's the easiest solution that evades you.